# When and how to redirect with Apollo Client and React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, apollo

lI have created a React component using Apollo and I currently use the render function to perform a redirect after data has loaded but I receive the warning: `Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within`render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.`

Here's my code:
https://gist.github.com/jmn/c3f7c4489cd5f759808a62b48352ce87

The redirect part:

```
render() {
    return (
      <Query query={Q} variables={{ cursor: this.props.match.params.id }}>
      {({ loading, error, data, fetchMore }) => {
        if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
        if (error) return <p>Error :(</p>;
        if (!this.props.match.params.id) {
          this.props.history.push(
            "/post/" + data.allPosts.pageInfo.endCursor
          );
        }
        return (
          <div></div>
        )
```

How can I do this in idiomatic React code and avoid any warnings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using React Router v4 although I'm not quite sure. As seen in the React Router [docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history/history-is-mutable)

> history is mutable

which is why calling `this.props.history.push()` is causing the above error. Instead, of mutating the history prop consider using the `<Redirect />` component like so:

```
if (!this.props.match.params.id) {
   return <Redirect to={"/post/" + data.allPosts.pageInfo.endCursor}
}
```

for more on `<Redirect />` see [here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I try this I get this error: "  Line 65:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
" on the <Redirect />

Comment: I made a function containing conditional <Redirect /> and called it from within the render functions return statement, that worked, thanks.

Comment: Sorry about that. I edited my answer above since you actually need to return the <Redirect /> component. Glad you figured it out